# Angular: Correct way to send parameters to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, url-parameters

I'm a bit new to Angular, and I am trying to get a grip on how to utilize Angular in  a "correct" way regarding directives.

My use-case is that I'm developing a 3D-project viewer with Angular & ThreeJS. A user can have different "projects" that is available for him to view.

The way we want to utilize the project identification is through url parameters, so that a person is able to link a specific project to other people to view.

The Viewer/Renderer is defined as a directive, so that we can define the viewer as following

```
...
    <viewer></viewer>
...
```

As I have understood it, there are some different ways to deliver the url parameters to the viewer-directive, and I'm trying to utilize $stateParams to access the parameter from the url. But as I continued working, there is no "clear" way to access the $stateParams, but you have to connect a controller to the directive, and then access it from there.

Is this the intended way to do this? Or should I define it as attributes to the viewer directive? If so, how do I access the url parameter in the html code? Or is there a third and better option?

As you probably understand I'm kinda new to angular, and I mainly want to get a grip of the intended usage of Angular, so that I don't screw up to much now at the start.

Best regards, David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your `url parameters via scope`, as you will be passing a string so `@` makes more sense here :

```
scope: {
    datasource: '@'
}
```

In your directive you can pass the value like this:

```
<viewer datasource={{urlParamValue}}></viewer>
```

And in your `controller`, you can gather the url params like this:

```
function Controller($scope, $location){
    var urlParamValue = $location.search().urlParamValue;    
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good apart from the scope declaration. First, you do not need a name behind `@` unless you want to rename your field. `datasource: '@datasource'` is redundant and equivalent to `datasource: '@'`. Second, you need either a one-way `<` or two-way `=` binding or you need to wrap your `urlParamValue` in curly brackets in your template. Otherwise you'll end up with the string `urlParamValue` instead of the actual url param in your directive.

Comment: @PerfectPixel: Ah thanks.. changed... i don't think so we need a two way data binding here... as its url parameters value and its mostly going to be string...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to utilize what you mentioned here. While it probably is a good design behind it, when you have just learned that you can inject a lot of cool parameters to your services and controllers, you get a bit frustrated when the same thing does not apply to directives.

Comment: If you want to optimize, you may use a one-time binding `{{::urlParamValue}}` as the parameter should not change without the view changing. By the way you could inject `$location` into your directive, however, it is not necessarily good design. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use as below for 2-way binding.

```
scope: {
    datasource: '=datasource'
}
```